# Why does this have to be $f(0)=g(0)$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

For the problem, I am not given any solution so no idea

> Prove that any two continuous maps $f,g; I \to X$ such that
>
> $$f(0)=g(0) \in X$$
>
> are homotopic where $I=[0,1]$ is the unit line.

I just thought, well

> $I \in \mathbb{R}$ which is convex, so I can have $h(s,t)=(1-t)f(s)+tg(s)$ as my homotopy.

...No? how should

> $$f(0)=g(0)$$

come into play to determine the solution? My reasoning would tell us in fact that any paths are homotopic which shouldn't be the case. I don't understand how I can solve this.

Comment: Completely unclear. I guess they mean homotopy rel $0$.

Comment: I just wrote the question in the way that is exactly written in the past papers I am looking at. The quetsion can't be any clearer now i hope

Comment: I mean to say that the point of their $f(0)=g(0)$ demand is unclear. Your question is fine.

Comment: So are you saying that my answer isn't entirely wrong?? The demand is redundant and does't matter whether it's there or not?

Comment: Is $I$ a closed interval?

Comment: Yes, it says $I=[0,1]$. I assume the notation is universaly understood as the closed interval

Comment: Is $X$ supposed to be $I$?

Comment: What does it mean to multiply an element of $X$ by a real number? Or to add two elements of $X$?

Answer (score 1):

If, for example, $X$ is not path-connected and $f(0)$ is in a different path component from $g(0)$, then $f$ and $g$ can't be homotopic.  But if $f(0) = g(0) = x$, then you can "homotope" both $f$ and $g$ to be the constant map $I \to X$ with value $x$, and therefore $f$ and $g$ are homotopic.

As @JackLee points out, your construction of a homotopy does not make sense because in general $X$ there is no notion of multiplying points by numbers or adding points together.

Comment: I really don't know how to tackle these problems...I mean, I often get told "your homotopy/map doesn't make sense" but I just don't know when it makes sense and when it doesn't. You mention that $X$ doesn't have multiplication of addition, but in cases like this ($S^1,D^2\setminus \{(0,0\}$, there is automatically addition mulitplication available (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775984/contradictory-homotopy-equivalence-and-deformation-retract-problem). Why is it that a circle can have multilcation/division/addition but not for some $X$? The $h$ in the answer looks similar to mine..

Comment: *meant to say multiplication OR addition, not "of" sorry

Comment: @Kydo What is the multiplication operation on, for example, a genus-2 surface? Just because some topological spaces have a compatible continuous binary operation does not mean they all do... in fact we give them a special name '[topological groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group)' or more generally '[H-spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-space)'.